# Html and css website not showing up on search engine

Tags: html, css

I have a website that I made in html and css. I registered the domain and I am hosting it using googledrive if you go into a browser and type in (websitename).com in the url it works but if you type it into google or bing search engine it dosnt come up. There were about 20 things that came up  and none of them were my site. I am using godaddy.com for my domain name. Do I have to enable something? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When did you begin hosting it?

Comment: There are at least 20 websites more important than yours.

Comment: I started hosting it this morning

Comment: You have a lot to learn, https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769 in a nut shell, it takes time!

Answer (score 1):

A few things you should know:

- You need to go into the Google Search Console and Bing Webmaster Tools (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) and add your website and submit a sitemap
- Websites aren't crawled and indexed immediately, it takes time. Also, your website may never rank, it depends on how relevant the search engines determine your content is (See this article on SEO http://searchengineland.com/guide/what-is-seo)

Also, you should post this in the Webmasters community, not here.